# Are there any advantages to separating lib.rs from main.rs?

Tags: rust, tdd

I'm a new to Rust. I'm currently building a webserver that works as a standalone. I have main.rs and several submodules. While studying to introduce TDD, I came across the following in the official [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch12-03-improving-error-handling-and-modularity.html#separation-of-concerns-for-binary-projects):

> Split your program into a main.rs and a lib.rs and move your program’s logic to lib.rs.

I think it's possible to add test while keeping main.rs, but I'm wondering if there's an advantage to splitting it into lib.rs, or if it's a general and implicit promise.

I also have additional questions. Do you prefer adding test module to the bottom of each module(.rs) or creating a test directory to keep them together? I wonder if I need to create a separate test directory to write it.

Comment: a crate can be used both as a library and multiple binaries. if you provide a `lib.rs` you can control what is exported in the library.

Comment: Some testing techniques are only possible with libraries. Fuzzing, e.g.

Comment: I do unit tests in the file directly, integration tests in the tests folder. Because then you can access non-pub elements in your unit tests, but not in your integration tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any advantages to separating lib.rs from main.rs?

I'd say this is more a matter of clean design, not about technical reasons:
If you do so, you can easily create multiple binaries sharing code from the lib. E.g., you could create one binary which implements a command line interface and another one with a GUI or a webserver for your library's logic. Testing is also way cleaner and easier if you have a library with a defined API.

> Do you prefer adding test module to the bottom of each module(.rs) or creating a test directory to keep them together? I wonder if I need to create a separate test directory to write it.

These are usually used for different types of test. The one in a module are meant for [*unit tests*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing), which should only but thoroughly test the functionality of that very module. Having the tests there has the advantage, that you can easily access and test non `pub` functions in the module.

The tests in the `tests` directory are meant for [*integration tests*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing). These test the public API of the whole library - how it is used by external applications and do the different calls interact correctly with each other.